# CUDA loop unrolling

Tags: cuda

I have some problem in loop unroll in CUDA.

In normal serial code:

```
//serial basic:
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    c[i] = a[i] + b[i];}

//serial loop unroll:
for(int i = 0; i < n/4; i++){
    c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
    c[i+1] = a[i+1] + b[i+1];
    c[i+2] = a[i+2] + b[i+2];
    c[i+3] = a[i+3] + b[i+3];}
```

So I think the CUDA loop unrolling looks like this:

```
int i = 2*(threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * gridDim.x);
a[i+0] = b[i+0] + c[i+0];
a[i+1] = b[i+1] + c[i+1];
```

But in the CUDA hand-book the unrolling example I can't understand

This is a normal GlobalWrite kernel:

```
__global__ void GlobalWrites( T *out, T value, size_t N )
{
for(size_t i = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
    i < N;
    i += blockDim.x*gridDim.x ) {
    out[i] = value;
    } 
 }
```

unrolling kernel:

```
template<class T, const int n> __global__ void Global_write(T* out, T value, size_t N){
size_t i;
for(i = n*blockDim.x*blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    i < N - n*blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
    i += n*gridDim.x*blockDim.x;)
    for(int j = 0; j < n; i++){
        size_t index = i + j * blockDim.x;
        outp[index] = value;
    }
for ( int j = 0; j < n; j++ ) {
    size_t index = i+j*blockDim.x;
    if ( index<N ) out[index] = value;
}}
```

I know this kernel uses less blocks but may someone explain why it works better (n=4,10% speed up).

Comment: Ask a new question. Don't change this one after you already received answers. You have one hour to save your edited text. After that I am rolling back your edit to the way your question was.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it wasn't obvious, because `n` is a template parameter, it is constant at compile time. This means that the compiler is free to optimize the constant trip count loop away by unrolling. It is, therefore, instructive to remove the template magic and unroll the loop by hand for the n=4 case you mentioned:

```
template<class T> 
__global__ void Global_write(T* out, T value, size_t N)
{
    size_t i;
    for(i = 4*blockDim.x*blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
        i < N - 4*blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
        i += 4*gridDim.x*blockDim.x;) {
            out[i + 0 * blockDim.x] = value;
            out[i + 1 * blockDim.x] = value;
            out[i + 2 * blockDim.x] = value;
            out[i + 3 * blockDim.x] = value;
    }
    if ( i+0*blockDim.x < N ) out[i+0*blockDim.x] = value;
    if ( i+1*blockDim.x < N ) out[i+1*blockDim.x] = value;
    if ( i+2*blockDim.x < N ) out[i+2*blockDim.x] = value;
    if ( i+3*blockDim.x < N ) out[i+3*blockDim.x] = value;
}
```

The unrolled inner loop yields four completely independent writes which are coalesced. It is this instruction level parallelism which give the code higher instruction throughput and improved performance. I highly recommend Vasily Volkov's [Unrolling Parallel Loops](https://www.nvidia.com/docs/IO/116711/sc11-unrolling-parallel-loops.pdf) from the GTC conference of a few years ago, if you haven't already seen it. His presentation lays out the theoretical background for why this type of loop unrolling is an optimisation in CUDA.

Answer (score 3):

In the templated kernel, `const int n` is known at compile time, allowing the compiler to actually unroll the `for(int j = 0; j < n; i++)` loop removing the conditional checks on that loop. If the loop size is not known at compile time, the compiler cannot unroll the loop. Simple as that.

Comment: You mean the for loop is automatic optimize by the compiler?

Comment: @Zziggurats That is what loop unrolling is. See talonmies answer for a better/fuller explanation.